# Renaming menu for Windows shell

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, menu, cmd

I wanted to create a simple renamer which helps me in my work! from .dat to .bmp .
I created this code: (In batch file)

```
@echo off
color 0a
title Renamer 
echo Are
ren *.bmp *.dat
echo Done 

pause
```

Now, I wanna add this option:

```
Rename dat > bmp - press a
Rename bmp > dat - press b
Close - press c
```

How to create such code in that way?

Answer (score 2):

you may try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
cls
cd "X:\MyPath\to\picture files"
set "enter=a"
:loop
echo [a] dat --^> bmp
echo [b] bmp --^> dat
set /p "enter=your choice (%enter%) "
if /i "%enter%"=="a" (
    ECHO ren *.dat *.bmp
) ELSE (
    if /i "%enter%"=="b" (
        ECHO ren *.bmp *.dat
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO  :loop
    )
)
```

Remove the `echo`  before `ren`, if it looks good.